# how to pass an object as renderView() parameter in symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

I have a problem with symfony 2 ( I'm pretty new with this framework and I would like to learn how to use correctly so I hope you can help me).

My problem is the following:

I want to show a product in a template and I need to pass some parameters like name, description and price about him:

```
public function showAction($id)
{
    $product = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeReadBundle:Product')->find($id);
    if(!$product)
    {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('error: not found');
    }
    $content = $this->renderView('AcmeReadBundle:Show:index.html.twig',$product);
    return new Response($content);
}
```

If I do this I have this error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller::renderView() must be of the type array, object given
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Define an array and try to place your object inside it.

Answer (score 6):

you did quite alright, except you should pass parameters to templates in an array and it is better to return rendered template directly!

```
public function showAction($id)
{
    $product = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeReadBundle:Product')->find($id);
    if(!$product)
    {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('error: not found');
    }
    return $this->render('AcmeReadBundle:Show:index.html.twig', array('product'=> $product));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to put:

```
$return $this->renderView('AcmeReadBundle:Show:index.html.twig',array('product' => $product));
```

you shoud pass parameters like array

Comment: Your answer is duplicate of first answer.

Answer (score 0):

If template **AcmeReadBundle:Show:index.html.twig** is made for **Product**, it is wrong to put another "product" prefix in front of expressions, like so:

```
{{ product.title }}
{{ product.price }}
```

**It is right** to look it like this:

```
{{ title }}
{{ price }}
```

in template. So wrapping is a bad option. **Best option is to use `get_object_vars()`**, it automatically converts object to an array:

```
return $this->render('AcmeReadBundle:Show:index.html.twig', get_object_vars($product));
```

This way you can use this template calling it from another template (because it doesn't contain "product"-prefix before every expression), when iterating thru `Products` collection for example, because your `Products` collection would contain collection of `Products`, not collection of `Arrays of 1 object which is Product`.